# I've got a few servo motor questions

Tags: servomotor, otherservos

How can I measure the amount of voltage I'm giving a servo motor? How can I give a servo motor the correct amount of power it needs to run at it's full potential? Say I had this motor:

**ANNIMOS 60KG Digital Servo 8.4V High Voltage Stainless Steel Gear Large Torque High Speed Waterproof Baja Servos - 180 Degrees**
(this is an example that I copied from amazon)

What does the 60KG mean? I assume that 8.4V High Voltage is the amount of power it needs to run at full potential. Large torque means it can lift a lot of weight, but how much?

I've tried to find answers to these questions, I've watched a lot of YouTube videos and read a lot of tutorials, but I found nothing about my questions. Thank you for taking the time to read  through this!

Answer (score 1):

That's a hobby servo, from a dubious source.  It's not a technical device marketed to technical people, so don't expect a datasheet that has technical, verifiable specifications.

There *are* hobby servos that come with specifications, and sometimes they even meet their claims.  If you want to buy one and have it Just Work, start with a company that lists said specifications, and that has a reputation for standing behind their work.

> What does the 60KG mean?

It's very possibly a model name.  Servos produce torque, and a kilogram is a unit of mass.  Even when misused as a unit of force (i.e., $\mathrm {kg} \cdot 9.8\mathrm{m/s}$ it's still not a torque.

> I assume that 8.4V High Voltage is the amount of power it needs to run at full potential.

If it were a *technical* specification, $\mathrm{8.4V}$ would be enough.  "High voltage" just indicates that it uses more than the old-style 4-cell Nicad pack (4.8V nominal, essentially between 4V and 5V).

Assuming that it's a quality part, "$\mathrm{8.4V}$" almost certainly means that it's designed to run off of two unregulated Lithium-Polymer batteries in series.  But you're buying a no-name part from an unreliable vendor.

> Large torque means it can lift a lot of weight, but how much?

"Large" is a marketing word, designed to make stop thinking long enough to buy the thing.  A real specification would list a torque in inch-pounds or Newton-meters.  A better specification would have short-term torque and holding torque (but you won't find that in a hobby servo from any source).

"Large" torque means it can twist hard.  Force = torque / diameter, so large torque means nothing in terms of how much weight it can lift unless you specify a lever arm.